# flink sql explode column and add index

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Is there any way to parse list into multiple row and add index in list use flink sql?

Here is the input example:

```json
{
    "uid":"123",
    "imp_content":[
        {"key":"#a#"},
        {"key":"#b#","search_flag":"5"},
        {"key":"#c#","adid":150690},
        {"key":"#d#","search_flag":"0"},
        {"key":"#e#","search_flag":"0"},
        {"key":"#f#","search_flag":"0"},
        {"key":"#g#","search_flag":"5"},
        {"key":"#x#","search_flag":"5"},
        {"key":"#i#","search_flag":"3"}
    ]
}
```

Here is the expected result:

| uid | idx | key | search_flag | adid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | #a# | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2 | #b# | 5 | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 123 | 9 | #i# | 3 | NULL |

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that does something similar. Given this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `flink_commits` (
  `author` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `authorDate` TIMESTAMP(3),
  `authorEmail` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `commitDate` TIMESTAMP(3),
  `committer` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `committerEmail` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `filesChanged` ARRAY<ROW<`filename` VARCHAR(2147483647), `linesAdded` INT, `linesChanged` INT, `linesRemoved` INT>>,
  `sha1` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  `shortInfo` VARCHAR(2147483647),
  WATERMARK FOR `commitDate` AS `commitDate` - INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
COMMENT 'Commits on the master branch of github.com/apache/flink'
WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  ...
);
```

you can do this:

```sql
SELECT
  sha1, filename, added, changed, removed
FROM
  flink_commits
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(filesChanged) AS files (filename, added, changed, removed);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to parse index of filename in `filesChanged` array? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, but perhaps you can find a good solution by applying a user-defined function.